# Join two dataframes and replace the original column values using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DFs

df1:

```
+---+-----+--------+
|key|price|    date|
+---+-----+--------+
|  1|  1.0|20210101|
|  2|  2.0|20210101|
|  3|  3.0|20210101|
+---+-----+--------+
```

df2:

```
+---+-----+
|key|price|
+---+-----+
|  1|  1.1|
|  2|  2.2|
|  3|  3.3|
+---+-----+
```

I'd like to replace `price` column values from `df1` with `price` values from `df2` where `df1.key == df2.key`

Expected output:

```
+---+-----+--------+
|key|price|    date|
+---+-----+--------+
|  1|  1.1|20210101|
|  2|  2.1|20210101|
|  3|  3.3|20210101|
+---+-----+--------+
```

I've found some solutions in python but I couldn't come up with a working solution in Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply join + drop `df1` column price:

```
val df = df1.join(df2, Seq("key")).drop(df1("price"))

df.show
//+---+-----+--------+
//|key|price|    date|
//+---+-----+--------+
//|  1|  1.1|20210101|
//|  2|  2.2|20210101|
//|  3|  3.3|20210101|
//+---+-----+--------+
```

Or if you have more entries in `df1` and you want to keep their `price` when there is no match in `df2` then use left join + coalesce expression:

```
val df = df1.join(df2, Seq("key"), "left").select(
  col("key"),
  col("date"),
  coalesce(df2("price"), df1("price")).as("price")
)
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your solution, and the order of the columns changed in the output df, i.e.: `key, date, price`. Is it possible to preserve the order?

Comment: @dmgcodevil Hi! just use `.select("key", "price", "date")` if you want them in that order

Comment: This is an easy example. What about variable json input replacing that variable input in a df?